# Apache Drill select from web files?

Tags: apache-drill

Is it possible Apache Drill to load json which is returned from web request?

For example if the json is located at: `http://myHost/data/today.json`

Comment: you can load json from file system (e.g. local file system, HDFS, etc) **not** from web reqest. But this can be interesting feature. Ask drill developers and users at user@drill.apache.org Check [MailingList](https://drill.apache.org/mailinglists/) for details

Comment: That would be a really helpful feature.

Answer (score 1):

Drill doesn't have an HTTP storage plugin, but if your web server happens to be backed by S3, you could query S3 directly.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html

http://drill.apache.org/docs/s3-storage-plugin/

Comment: Unfortunately it's not. I'll make some script to download it before it's needed.